# Access database import from excel file fails when AssocID (first field) is mixed with integers and strings

Tags: vba, excel, record

I have an access database with vba code that is attempting to access an excel sheet and copy the data to a recordset using DAO.recordset.  If all of the column (assocId) is integer the import works wonderfully if all are strings it works but if you have a mixed back (eg 111111 | Vinny | etc and then on row two you have JOE-1 | Joe | etc) the import will fail.  It says "You cannot record your changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table"

Here is the offending sub:

```
    Public Sub LoadFileInfo()
    'Load information from selected file
    On Error GoTo ErrorHappened
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastTransType As String
Dim transactionCounter As Integer
Dim currentRecord As CurrentImportRecord
Dim wtf As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(selectTransTypesSql &   GetSetting("PayrollManualImportExportTransactionTypes") & ")")
ReDim transTypes(DCount("TransType", "MasterTransactionTypes", "IsActive <> 0")) As MasterTransactionTypes

rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF


    'Add each transaction type and desc to the Private Type and increment the appropriate counter
    GetMasterTransactionTypes rs!TransType, rs!TransDesc, i
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop
rs.Close

Set db = OpenDatabase(importFileName, False, True, "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & "[" & GetSheetName(importFileName) & "$]" & " ORDER BY TransType")

rs.MoveLast
importFields = vbNullString
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
    importFields = importFields & rs.Fields(i).Name & ","
Next

fullImport = (rs.Fields.count > 4)

i = 0
transactionCounter = 1

lblFile.Caption = "File name: " & importFileName
Dim rowNum As Variant
rowNum = rs.RecordCount
wtf = rs.GetRows(rowNum)

ReDim ledgerEntries(rs.RecordCount) As PayrollLedgerImport
'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows; if so push transaction objects to private type array
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    currentRecord.associateId = CStr(rs!assocId)
    currentRecord.transactionType = rs!TransType
    currentRecord.transactionNotes = CStr(rs!TransNotes)

    If lastTransType = CStr(currentRecord.transactionType) Then
        transactionCounter = transactionCounter + 1
    Else
        transactionCounter = 1
    End If
    If IsValidTransType(currentRecord.transactionType) Then
        If Not fullImport Then
            currentRecord.transactionAmount = rs!TransAmount
            GetPayrollTransactions currentRecord.associateId, currentRecord.transactionType, currentRecord.transactionAmount, currentRecord.transactionNotes, i, transactionCounter
        Else
            currentRecord.transactionAmount = rs!TransAmt
            GetPayrollTransactions currentRecord.associateId, currentRecord.transactionType, currentRecord.transactionAmount, currentRecord.transactionNotes, i, transactionCounter
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox (currentRecord.transactionType & ": Not A Valid Transaction Type")
    End If
    lastTransType = rs!TransType
    rs.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop

FormatFileInformationWindow
cmdImportFile.Enabled = True


End Sub
```

I've been at this for hours.  I've tried casting all the columns when I take them in and I get the same issue.  Works fine for all ints or all strings but in reality some of our employees have string and some have int for employee ID.  I tried taking them all in as string converting where necessary but that didn't work either.  Only thing that works is two sheets - one containing strings one containing ints.

Comment: Is it giving an error on the line currentRecord.associateId = CStr(rs!assocId) or is it giving it elsewhere?

Comment: What is the field data type is associd?

Comment: @PKatona - yes you are correct it is giving it on currentRecord.associateId = CStr(rs!assocId).  But I think its the original set of the recordset that makes my rs!assocId field equal to the error I mentioned in the original post because when I step through on the record previous to the offending one it works fine and then steps into the next record and the RS is already set to the error.  It has to be that but I dont know why.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the field type in access is text, in the underlying sql table (these are linked) its varchar(6)

Comment: It may be the length

Comment: 2200 rows?  That's strange also when I remove all the string values its only 186 it runs fine about 2004 rows.  So I'm not sure if it is the length.

Comment: Can you show the definition of "CurrentImportRecord"?

Comment: `Private Type CurrentImportRecord
    associateId As String
    transactionType As Integer
    transactionAmount As Double
    transactionNotes As String
End Type`

Comment: Try changing `"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"` to `"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes"` - the IMEX part signifies mixed data types